# Creating a new Java Enterprise Application and deploying it in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm a beginner using netbeans and glassfish so please take it easy on me.
What I have done is File->New Project->Java Enterprise Application

The Glassfish version is 4.1.1

After the project has been created, I right click on it and select deploy.

But then I get this error

```
GlassFish Server 4.1.1 is running.
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1.1
Initial deploying DS_Project to /Users/user1/NetBeansProjects/My_Project/dist/gfdeploy/My_Project
Completed initial distribution of My_Project
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false
/Users/user1/NetBeansProjects/My_Project/nbproject/build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 26 seconds)
```

The line in build-impl.xml that is causing the error is this

```
<nbdeploy clientModuleUri="${client.module.uri}" clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Comment: Did you build the project before trying to deploy it?

Comment: Yes I did, I right clicked on the project and selected build. the project builds successfully. Is there anything else I could provide in my question that could help solve this?

Comment: The Glassfish server log could provide a more detailed message of the error.